# Work around spaced-filenames in array construction

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I'm using the command `files=( $(ls "/path/wanted") )` to store all filenames from a directory in an array. However filenames that contain space character result in multiple array entries.

> **To figure out:**
>
> ```
> ls /path/wanted 
> something.txt 
> spaced name
> ```
>
> ```
> ${#files[@]} 
> 3
> ```

How could I map the whole filename to each array position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
shopt -s nullglob # enable nullglob
#shopt -s dotglob # enable dotglob too if desired

cd /path/wanted
files=( * )
cd -

# do something with "${files[@]}" or "${#files[@]}"

shopt -u nullglob # disable nullglob
#shopt -u dotglob # disable dotglob if enabled
```

With `nullglob` disabled (default) the array would contain one element containing the glob pattern `*` if there are no files in the directory. 
With `nullglob` enabled the array will be empty.

The same applies to `dotglob`: If disabled, dotfiles must be matched explicitly with a pattern like `.[^.]*` (the `[^.]` is used to *not* match the current directory `.` and the parent directory `..`). 
With `dotglob` enabled, the pattern `*` also matches files starting with a dot.

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: Maybe `files=( /path/wanted/* )`

Comment: Sure, that works too if it is okay to store the complete path to each file.

Comment: I don￻'t see why that would be a problem, but in that case, this `files=( * )` works perfectly well without a loop.

Comment: @Isaac There's no problem at all and you're right. No loop needed here. Thank you!